# Ler código Json PHP

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando ler esse json a baixo mais não estou conseguindo, qual seria a maneira mais fácil de listar ele por mais que já vi outros exemplos por aqui não encontrei algo que me ajude a formatar minha saida... obrigado a todos

```
{
"makerCommission": 0,
"takerCommission": 0,
"buyerCommission": 0,
"sellerCommission": 0,
"canTrade": true,
"canWithdraw": false,
"canDeposit": false,
"updateTime": 1637592080302,
"accountType": "SPOT",
"balances": [
    {
        "asset": "BNB",
        "free": "1000.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
        "asset": "BTC",
        "free": "1.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
        "asset": "BUSD",
        "free": "10000.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
        "asset": "ETH",
        "free": "100.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
        "asset": "LTC",
        "free": "500.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
        "asset": "TRX",
        "free": "500000.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
        "asset": "USDT",
        "free": "10000.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
        "asset": "XRP",
        "free": "50000.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "SPOT"
]
}
```

PHP

```
$url="";
$output=file_get_contents($url);
$output=json_decode($output);
//print_r($output);
foreach ($output as $ke) {
 $acc =$ke->accountType;
 $balances =$ke->balances;


echo '<br>';
 
}
```

Comment: O primeiro texto não é um JSON válido.

Comment: E não é nada parecido com o retorno da URL em questão no segundo código.

Comment: corrigi o json no exemplo

Comment: O JSON em si representa um objeto, não um array, então não é necessário fazer o `foreach` tal como fez.

Answer (score -1):

Você gostaria de exibir todos os dados na tela?

Se sim, o caminho é realmente utilizar o Foreach, mas utilizando uma verificação dentro para executar outro caso o item atual seja mais um array(object) como no caso dos Balances.

Comment: sim gostaria de exibir todos